# How to avoid StackOverflowError for a recursive function

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm writing a function that will call itself up to about 5000 times. Ofcourse, I get a `StackOverflowError`. Is there any way that I can rewrite this code in a fairly simple way?:

```
void checkBlocks(Block b, int amm) {

    //Stuff that might issue a return call

    Block blockDown = (Block) b.getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN);
    if (condition) 
        checkBlocks(blockDown, amm);


    Block blockUp = (Block) b.getRelative(BlockFace.UP);
    if (condition) 
        checkBlocks(blockUp, amm);

    //Same code 4 more times for each side

}
```

By the way, what is the limitation of how deep we may call the functions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stack-overflow-error

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use an explicit stack of objects and a loop, rather than the call stack and recursion:

```
void checkBlocks(Block b, int amm) {
  Stack<Block> blocks = new Stack<Block>();
  blocks.push(b);
  while (!blocks.isEmpty()) {
    b = blocks.pop();
    Block blockDown = (Block) b.getRelative(BlockFace.DOWN);
    if (condition)
      blocks.push(block);
    Block blockUp = (Block) b.getRelative(BlockFace.UP);
    if (condition) 
      blocks.push(block);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

default stack size in java is 512kb. if you exceed that program will terminate throwing StackOverflowException

you can increase the stack size by passing a JVM argument :
-Xss1024k

now stack size is 1024kb. you may give higher value based on your environment

I don't think we can programmatically change this

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the stack size by using -Xss4m.

Comment: But what if the board size just keeps increasing? I think he realized this and did not ask how to increase the stack size, but rather how to refactor the code!

Answer (score 0):

You may put your "Block"s into a queue/stack and iterate as long as Blocks are available.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that you get StackOverflow with such branching factor of your recursion. In other languages it can be achieved [by Tail Call Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). But I suppose your problem needs another way to solve.

Ideally, you perform some check on Block. Maybe you can obtain list of all blocks and check each of them iteratively?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases recursion is used in a wrong way. You shouldn't get a stack over flow exception. 
Your method has no return type/value. 
How do you ensure your initial Block b is valid?

If you are using recursion, answer yourself the following question:

- what is my recursion anchor (when do i stop with recursion)
- what is my recursion step (how do I reduce my number of calculations)

Example:

- n! => n*n-1!

my recursion anchor is n == 2 (result is 2), so I can calculate all results beginnging from this anchor.

my recursion step is n-1 (so each step I get closer to the solution (and in this fact to my recursion anchor))