# Better Way to iterate through those ArrayLists?

Tags: java

I have the following Code:

```
/**
 * Calculates all correct Moves for Figure f which are possible
 * @param f the Figure for which you want to check it's moves
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<Move> checkMoves(Figure f) {
    ArrayList<Move> moves = this.expand(f.getLocation(), new ArrayList<Move>(), false, this.getPlayer(f.getOwner()));

    // Fix the wrongly calculated moves
    for(Move m : moves) {
        moves = this.jumpFix(moves, m);
    }

    return moves;
}

/**
 * Takes a look into all calculated moves and finds those which should be seen as one move, but are still
 * considered to be more than one move (several jumps in one move)
 */
private ArrayList<Move> jumpFix(ArrayList<Move> moves, Move m) {
    ArrayList<Move> consecutive = this.findConsecutiveMoves(moves, new ArrayList<Move>(), m);

    if(consecutive.size() > 0) {
        m.getTarget().setX(consecutive.get(consecutive.size() - 1).getTarget().getX());
        m.getTarget().setY(consecutive.get(consecutive.size() - 1).getTarget().getY());
    }

    for(Move i : consecutive) {
        moves.remove(i);
        m.addStop(i.getTarget());
    }

    return moves;
}

/**
 * Finds all consecutive moves to the given move m, that share their start and target cells
 */
public ArrayList<Move> findConsecutiveMoves(ArrayList<Move> moves, ArrayList<Move> deleteable, Move m) {
    for(Move n : moves) {
        if(n.getStart().equalTo(m.getTarget())) {
            deleteable.add(n);
            deleteable = this.findConsecutiveMoves(moves, deleteable, n);
        }
    }

    return deleteable;
}
```

Explanation:
- checkMoves calculates all possible Moves for given Figure f
- After expand() calculated all possible moves, several of those "moves" might be sondered one move, if they are connected (Example: A Move is going from a to b. If we now have several Moves a -> b, b -> c, c -> d this would be the Move a -> d)
- I need to remove all those little consecutive moves and set a -> b to a -> d
- I am trying to iterate through the whole moves List and start findConsecutiveMoves for each m, checking if there are consecutive moves.

1. I do get a StackOverflowError. I suppose my way of doing things is not good. How can i improve it?
2. I fear I will get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in case the program finds consecutive moves, since I'm iterating over moves while changing it. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Put in a list the index of removed items and iterate again on the list with these index to add the new item.

Answer (score 0):

The stackoverflow error occurs due to recursive method calls, you must check your logic for any recursive method calls, to avoid the

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
```

You should use the Collections.synchronizedCollection(Collection c) method which will provide you a thread safe collection, One more thing about iterating, if you are using JAVA 8 then you should checkout the streams API which provides better and efficient way for iterating.

Comment: @ I checked my findConsecutiveMoves() function several times. I cannot find any flaws in it's logic. There just has to be a better way to find all consecutive ones?

Comment: Here is better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073471/java-how-to-avoid-stackoverflowexception

Comment: One more, read the answer of Derek Elkins in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951635/how-to-handle-stackoverflowerror-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`StackOverflowError` means you have to many recursive calls. Probably your findConsecutiveMoves goes into an infinite loop (checking nightbours in a infinite loop). To solve this, mark your Moves you have already checked and only check next Moves which are not marked yet.

To prevent `ConcurrentModificationException` Add a list, where you store deleteable Moves. After the whole iteration is finshed you can delete every Move that is in this list, while you are not iteration of your Moves list.