# I've got infinite looping

Tags: java

i am practicing my java by counting possible ways to reach n with a dice.
and when input n value to smaller number, it works.
but when i input n value to 100, it got infinite looping.

can u guys help me ?

here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    testCode test = new testCode();

    System.out.println(test.countWays(100));
}

 private static int countWays(int n)
    {
        if(n<=1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("counting ....");
            return countWays(n-6) + countWays(n-5) + countWays(n-4) + countWays(n-3) + countWays(n-2) + countWays(n-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No looping here. You've got *infinite **recursion***

Comment: .... but it doesn't look infinite actually, just very large.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Actually it's not infinite recursion, but before it reaches the base case it most likely hits stack overflow.

Comment: Yep, try it with a smaller number, say 10

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: caught that.

Comment: Consider: Every single time you call `countWays` with `n > 1`, you trigger six further calls to it. Each of those triggers six further calls (e.g., 36 more; 43 so far if you're counting); each of those 36 triggers six further calls (259 so far), and so on, and so on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder So then something like `6^100` function calls.  Yes, this should overflow the call stack.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay i see, that's why ! but what if i want the large number to works? i'm sorry i can't tag all of you

Comment: @user2871904, try changing your implementation similarly to how it is suggested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073471/java-how-to-avoid-stackoverflowexception)

Comment: Then use a non-recursive solution such as by using a stack. Edit: and now I see, this is exactly as @MikhailProkhorov recommends as well.

Comment: @MikhailProkhorov okay i will change it , i will post the update later.. thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is similar to Fibonnaci's one :

```
x0 = 0, x1 = 1, x(N) = x(N-2) + x(N-1)
```

If you need to do it with big numbers you should use a non-recursive method :

```
static long countBis(int n) {
        long fn, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6;
        int i;
        f1=f2=f3=f4=f5=f6=fn = 1;
        for ( i = 2; i <= n; i++ ) {
            f6 = f5;      
            f5 = f4;      
            f4 = f3;
            f3 = f2;
            f2 = f1;
            f1 = fn;
            fn = f6 + f5 + f4 + f3 + f2 + f1;
        }
        return fn;
    }
```

At each iteration you just calculate the sum of the precedent ones

I've tested with `n = 32` => with yours it took 8sec, with this one it took less than 1sec (I tried with `n = 1000` => always 1sec, but i didn't try yours haha, after `n = 35` it's a bit long ^^

Comment: WOW, it works ! thankyou very much sir. but can i ask u question? why i=2?

Comment: Thanks, just because i have `i<=n` then, it can be changed in : `i=1 ; i<n`
To do like you, because if you set `n=5` you'll do `(n-1)` iterations until `1`, so I coded to do same as you, from `1` include to `n` exclude : `(n-1)` iterations